# Auto delete na base de dados quando cookie expira

Tags: php

Olá, estou com uma duvida, no meu site eu tenho um sistema de login que quando os dados são validos, o sistema gera uma hash que armazena num cookie no navegador, e guarda na base de dados uma associação dessa hash com o id do perfil do usuário! Mas eu queria que quando o cookie desaparecesse do navegador automaticamente seja deletado da base de dados essa associação, por questões de segurança! Alguém sabe como isso se faz?

Comment: Você pode verificar sempre que efectuar login se existe algum registo da hash do utilizador na base de dados. Caso exista um registo na BD e não exista cookie, então elimine a hash da BD.

Comment: Você poderia salvar também a data de expiração do cookie na base de dados. Dai, qualquer usuário ao efetuar o login, verifique se essa data é menor que a data atual e delete todos os registros onde essa data é menor que a data atual.